# Datatables export to excel is not working with mozila firefox browser

Tags: jquery, export-to-excel, mozilla

I have  a datatable which is holding some value i want to export it to excel or pdf as the options are given with the sSwfPath ,it is working fine for IE and Chrome but in mozila only the print button is showing.Can anyone help me in this regard? i am posting my code here

```
$('#mainTable').dataTable({

            dom: 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
            tableTools: {
                "sSwfPath": "http://cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.3/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
            },
        "scrollY":        300,
        "scrollCollapse": true,
        "jQueryUI":       true,
        "aaSorting": [],

    });
```

Why mozila is showing only the print button ,can anyone expain ?? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Looks like Firefox doesn't enable Flash by default. Make sure you have the latest version of Flash installed. Go to add-ons, enable Flash and refresh. Did the trick for me.